How to solve "Sagen Sie es Anders!" type question? (General sentence reformulation)

Sagen Sie es Anders
Q: Befragungen machen deutlich (1), dass zwei Drittel der Verbraucher sich (2) beim Kauf von Lebensmitteln (3) nicht ausreichend über deren Qualität informiert fühlen(2).

Synonym

Nominaliserung

Satzumformung verbalisierung


die Vorlage:
Befragungen__ (A), dass __ (B), nicht ausreciehd über die Qualität informiert zu sein, wenn __ (C)

Here is my attempt so far:
a. We can disregard the part "... nicht ausreichend über deren Qualität informiert.." since that is already contained in the template.
b. For 1., I am thinking of putting zeigen but my problem is, does zeigen mean the same as make clear? Couldn't something be gezeigt but still not made clear?
I can do the nominalisierung and verbalisierung individually.
sich fühlen--> das Gefühl

is a bit more complicated. We see a "von" which mean it is a nominaliserung from something without an article. However, when thinking of the verbalisierung, how do I find the subject? I am guessing it should be something like:

beim Kauf von Lebensmittel-->Der Verbraucher kaufen Lebensmittel.
with subject being same as that of the original sentence.
It's not clear to me now, how to glue these parts back into the original sentence together....

It must be von Lebensmitteln in the question. Dative plural has that extra -n on  the noun.

It was my mistake in transcribing the question @Janka

I would have put it as:

Befragungen zeigen, dass zwei Drittel der Verbraucher das Gefühl haben, nicht ausreichend über die Qualität informiert zu sein, wenn sie Lebensmittel kaufen.

Your thinking about the individual problems is correct.

Could you explain the logic of the new words you inserted, and also identified which part goes where in the template? Thanks

1 says you should use a synonym, so the alternative goes at the same position.

3 says you should resolve the noun phrase „beim Kauf vom Lebensmitteln“. That means turning it into a verb phrase in the context. A präposition as bei marks an adverbial so the resulting verb phrase must be an adverbial clause. That's the clause starting with wenn. The other clause starts with dass, which marks an object clause (sometimes a subject clause) but not an adverbial clause.

beim Kauf von Lebensmitteln → wenn sie Lebensmittel kaufen The subject of that clause is the same as that of the higher level (object) clause. As you have to invent it from thin air. It's not in the original noun phrase. That's why it must be Verbraucher or sie.

2 says you should turn sich … fühlen into a noun phrase. It must go at the remaining position B, which is an object clause. That's why it becomes das Gefühl haben. As you still need a clause.
